# Front I/O ports on the front of a case

Tags: motherboard, case

I have seen so many cases with front usb ports etc, but obviously they couldn't fit **every** motherboard, so I was wondering how they connect, do they come with a plug that connects to a sata port or pci express or something, my question is just: how do those front i/o ports connect and interact with the computer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are pretty much standardized and are just little pins that stick up in a certain configuration:[image]

These pins look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

They're just electrical extensions of ports already found on the motherboard, just as an extension cord is an electrical extension of the wall socket.

Comment: as in, if my motherboard doesn't fit, too bad?

Comment: Yes, though they're pretty common these days. You may also be able to buy a PCI card that gives you additional ports including internally, but don't quote me, check around for that.